# Getting a keying error - > Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details

Tags: apt, updates, repository, gnupg

I am new to ubuntu it was working just fine after some time when i tried to update i ran to this error

```
(base) siddharth@Siddharth:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for siddharth:
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [119 kB]
Hit:3 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt jammy-pgdg InRelease
Hit:4 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:5 https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian  InRelease
Err:6 https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian  Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 34.225.25.188 443]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [107 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages [943 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main Translation-en [204 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages [881 kB]
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Reading package lists... Done
W: http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/jammy-pgdg/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
E: The repository 'https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian  Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Getting this error when i tried to sudo apt update

Comment: Tried few commands and now i am stuck at this error 


`E: The repository 'https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian  Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.`

Comment: That is I believe an invalid entry; trying opening it with your browser?  ie. it was incorrect to add it and it should thus be removed (*or at minimum commented out which has the effect of disabling it*). The official guide is https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu but how you do it is up to you; you could reverse how it was added; me I'd just go to terminal & removed it with a text editor  (*I add a date/time line as comment near my change detailing why it was added; I'll remove this at the same time most probably*).

Comment: yep i deleted the contents in that folder and then the error was gone.. thanks for the help @guiverc